# Travis CI ignore line

Tags: travis-ci

Problem:
I am using Travis CI and all of my builds are failing for this one project because there is a linting error on 1 line of my code. The code is written correctly but there is a linting error caused by a built in function name.

Question:
How do I tell Travis to ignore that line of code?

Answer (score 2):

Put this comment at the end of the line:

// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you writing in? Which linting tool are you using?

Rather than telling Travis to ignore that line of code, you will need to find either a per-line configuration flag, or a configuration file setting to get your linting tool to ignore that line of code.

Comment: Php and phpcs using the WordPress coding standards